# set Jmeter System.property in Ant Script

Tags: ant, jmeter

After some search, I found this website gives details of parameters that I can use jmeter with ant script   http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/

But I can't find a way to put these two lines from jmeter's system.property into Ant script

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore= file path

javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

tried this but doesn't work

```
<sysproperty key="javax.net.ssl.keyStore" value="performance/key/keyfile.p12"/>
```

Any idea how would this work? Do I have to make edit in `system.property` file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made this work with `<jvmarg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path/>` in ant script, not doing anything in system.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You can either put them in `system.properties` file or use jmeter variables `${__P(request.keystore)}` in `system.properties` and write:

```
<property name="request.keystore" value="filename"/>
```

Comment: This is what I did and still doesn't work, any idea? what I did wrong??

In system.properties file
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=${__P(request.keystore)}
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=${__P(request.keystorepassword)}
and this in the ant script
<property name="request.keystore" value="performance/key/filename.p12"/>
<property name="request.keystorepassword" value="password"/>

Comment: Are u doing remote testing?If yes,then add in property line remote="true"

Comment: No, I am not doing remote testing

Comment: In the system.properties file. If I use javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\\Users\\......\\xx.p12 Does work. but want not ${__P(request.keystore)} with property in ant.

Comment: I just made this work with <jvmarg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path/> in ant script, not doing anything in system.properties file. Thank for your help.